# mysqld starts properly but i am not able to access it on rhel5

Tags: mysql

`mysqld` starts properly but i am not able to access it on rhel5, when i enter `mysql` command it return nothing, but when i enter `/usr/bin/mysql` it starts properly

[root@192 log]# `service mysqld stop`
^[[A^[[Stopping mysqld:                                    [  OK  ]
[root@192 log]# `service mysqld start`
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
[root@192 log]# mysql

^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 mysql
[root@192 log]# mysql
^Z
[3]+  Stopped                 mysql
[root@192 log]# /usr/bin/mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1912
Server version: 5.1.61-log Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> \q

any help to fix this issue.

Comment: What say : which mysql

Comment: looks like you get in fine, once you get into bin directory and run it. Change you path so you don't have to. Am I missing something here?